# Specs met, but still: IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information

Tags: php, http, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-ipn

I've been trying to integrate my website with the PayPal IPN, but I've been unsuccessful so far. The Paypal documentation [HERE: SSL Certificate Upgrade Microsite](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1766&expand=true&locale=en_US) entails some specifications that need be met. My server supports **SHA-256** and uses **VeriSign G2 Root Certificate** as well. I've installed SSL on this domain too, but still I get nothing with the Paypal IPN.

I have a file IPNSampleCode.php at ***(NOT MY REAL WEBSITE)*** `https://XYXYXYX.com/IPN/IPNSampleCode.php` which is supposed to be called by the Instant Payment Notification (IPN) Simulator, but I keep getting 'IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information.
' whenever I run the IPN simulator against the IPN handler URL '`https://XYXYXYX.com/IPN/IPNSampleCode.php`'

What could I be missing, or what might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**

Comment: I just recently helped somebody with this same issue.  It turned they were using WordPress and had a "maintenance mode" plugin installed with maintenance mode active, so requests to their IPN URL were getting a bad response back since the maintenance mode wouldn't let it load.  You may want to check that your server isn't returning some weird result like that.  I would check your htaccess file for anything interesting first of all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for contacting PayPal Merchant Technical Services, I apologize for the delay in responding to your email.

We are aware of this issue with our IPN Simulator and our development team is working on a fix. Until this issue is fixed, I'd suggest running your IPN tests by making payments in Sandbox as we do send IPN requests with every payment.

If you have a similar issue with your payment tests, please let us know and we can take a look.

My apologies for the inconvenience caused.